# Commandline tz and ntp

Tags: ntp, timezone

What is the easiest way to set an incoming ntp server and then set the local tz so the ntp is syncing correctly?

Comment: I understand "set an incoming NTP server" as "configure my NTP *client* to use an NTP server", not as "setting up a local NTP server". @conma293, maybe you can clarify the question?

Comment: thats correct zwets, sorry was a bit vague

Comment: ntp does not care about time zones. ntp will sync regardless of what time zone you have  selected.

Comment: so is ntp always in utc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To configure your system's timezone, either from a terminal run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

or via the GUI open the application "Time & Date" (in the dash type "time" and it will show up) and set your location.

To configure NTP servers, if you have the (default) `ntpdate` package installed, edit `NTPSERVERS` in `/etc/default/ntpdate`, or if you (additionally) have the `ntp` package installed, edit `/etc/ntp.conf`.